# Javascript no hace el GET

Tags: javascript, get

Estoy haciendo una pagina para poder insertar datos en la base de datos, de forma que desde del frontend pueda introducir unos datos y se los envie al back-end, que mediante PHP se insertan estos datos.

La parte de PHP funciona perfectamente, y la de front-end a medias. Solo funciona cuando utilizo el debugger en firefox, mientras que si lo ejecuto de forma norma, no hace la conexion con el back-end, por lo que no envia los datos.

Me imagino que el problema debe estar en la funcion showUser(...), pero no se exactamente el que.....

El codigo de front-end:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lateral.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">


    function showUser(asig,uni,cur,cua,car) {

            window.alert("entro");
            window.alert(asig+"  "+uni+""+cur+""+cua+""+car+"");
            if (asig == "" ) {

                   window.alert("Sum shit");
                   window.alert(asig+"  "+uni+""+cur+""+cua+""+car+"");

                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }


                xmlhttp.open("GET","/insertar_a?asig="+asig+"&uni="+uni+"&cur="+cur+"&cua="+cua+"&car="+car,true);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                       document.getElementById("boi").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                        window.alert("sum shit2");
                        window.alert(asig+"  "+uni+""+cur+""+cua+""+car+"");

                    }
                };

                xmlhttp.send();



            }
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="boi">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group" style="width: 600px;">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Inserte Asignatura</label>
        <input id="asignatura"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Asignatura">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="width: 600px;">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Inserte Universidad</label>
        <input id="Universidad" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Universidad">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="width: 600px;">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Inserte Carrera</label>
        <input id="Carrera" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Carrera">

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="width: 100px;">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Inserte Curso</label>
        <input id="Curso" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >

      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="width: 150px;">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Inserte cuatrimestre</label>
        <input id="cuatrimestre" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" >

      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('asignatura').value,document.getElementById('Universidad').value,document.getElementById('Curso').value,document.getElementById('cuatrimestre').value,document.getElementById('Carrera').value)">Submit</button>
    </form>

    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Como podran ver utilizo componentes boostrap, pero no creo que eso influya en porque pasa lo descrito anteriormente...

Comment: ¿Este alert: `window.alert(asig+"  "+uni+""+cur+""+cua+""+car+"");` muestra los datos correctamente? ¿Este alert se muestra: `window.alert("sum shit2");`?  Por cierto, es muy penosa la forma en que le envías los datos a Javascript. Eso lo puedes recoger sin tener que mandarlo en parámetro de esta forma: `onclick="showUser(document.getElementById('asignatura').value,document.getElementById('Universidad').value,document.getElementById('Curso').value,document.getElementById('cuatrimestre').value,document.getElementById('Carrera').value)` ...

Comment: Cuando estoy con el debugger si se muestra el alert "sum shit2", y los datos se muestran bien.

Comment: ¿Y el problema entonces cuál es? ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador de forma normal sencillamente no envia los datos por algun motivo, pero si lo ejecuto con el modo debbug si. Y por eso puse el post, porque no se si es por algo de la asincronia de javascript, porque hice algo mal , etc...

Comment: ¿Aquí `insertar_a` no te falta ponerle la extensión `.php`, o estás haciendo redirección desde un controlador?

Comment: Estoy usando laravel, por lo que la direccion es controlada por el framework.